# Countdown timer set with a button

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I wanted to program a timer that can be set up by clicking a button. For example button one sets a timer to 1 minute. Button 2 sets the timer to 2 minutes. the third button should start and stop the timer. I tried many code samples but it is not running. Has someone an idea how to solve this?

```
public void mittelBtn (View view){

    EditText timerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    timerText.setText("7:00");

    countDownTimer =new CountDownTimer(420000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}

public void weichPlusBtn (View view){

    EditText timerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    timerText.setText("5:00");

    countDownTimer =new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: welol you probably want to set the timerTExt in onTick oO

Comment: I also found a `countDownTimer.cancel();` method which should work for the 3rd button

Comment: You are setting count down in button 1 and 2 and want to start it in 3rd?

Comment: yes, one first two buttons should set the different counting timers and with a third controlling button i want to start and stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Because in onTick you should do something.

```js
public void weichPlusBtn (View view){

    EditText timerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerText);

    timerText.setText("5:00");
    
    //Set a couter variable
    int counter = 5 * 60;

    countDownTimer =new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          counter--;
          String newTime = secondsToString(counter);
          timerText.setText(newTime);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
    
 private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", pTime / 60, pTime % 60);
    }
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.